# Reduce points to only ones that need to be drawn

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, drawing, geometry

I have a large complex geometry that I am drawing on to a 256x256 pixel tile. The geometry consists of quite a dense area and a more sparse area. This means that using a reduce algorithm such as douglas-peucker doesn't yield very good results for this scenario.

What I would like to do is only include pixels from the geometries that haven't already been drawn. IE I could have a geometry that runs from x=0,y=0 to x=256,y=256. I then have a geometry that runs from x=0,y=0 to x=0,y=256, to x=256,y=256. Therefore because I have already effectively drawn x=0,y=0 and x=256,y=256 from the first geometry I would only need to include and draw x=0,y=256 of the second geometry.

At the moment I have 100's of thousands of points trying to be rendered on the tile and it takes about a minute to complete. Is there anything I can eliminate the points already drawn without losing any of the geometry detail?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Isn't BitmapCache only beneficial when rendering to a UI element? Will I get a performance boost if just rendering to an image to save on disk?

Comment: I think Z-buffer will actually slow things down (if+memread~=memwrite). what kind of geometry do you have ? filled polygons,or just lines, what color( single color or different colors,or some mixing of overlapping pixels),... how complex geometry (number of lines,triangles ?) maybe you have just very badly programed rendering.